# update eclipse java to EE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I'm working with a version of eclipse.
I want to update my version.
I have "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers", but I need somes things on "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" (EE version). Mostly I want the web part.

So did theres a way inside the software for updating to EE?

tank you

(I'm using windows version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to help/install new software. And download the necessary plugins. You can change perspective to JAVA EE.

Comment: tank you, I look into new software and install xml web EE package from The Eclipse Project Updates site. I think I get all I need.